# Openstack-Install - Problem with juju bootstrap

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, openstack-autopilot, debootstrap

Having problems running Openstack-Install, using MAAS and Autopilot.
Getting error `Problem with juju bootstrap.`
Complete .cloud-install/commands.log file: 
http://pastebin.com/ANBMZwLs

It deploys a node, and fails after about 1500 sec. From the logfile it seems its not reaching some archives? But I am able to run `apt-get update` on both the deployed node over ssh, and the MaaS server it self.

I have two networks, one public(192.168.10.0) and one private for the nodes (10.10.10.0), MAAS server is acting as proxy for the Nodes.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your selected network architecture, private network(your nodes) must have access to Internet, and it seems in yours do not have access to Internet.

You must enable nat on your region controller following instructions in this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing

**1. step one - considering private network connected to eth1:**

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i eth1 -s 10.10.10.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

**2. Save the iptables:**

```
sudo iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/iptables.sav
```

**3. Edit /etc/rc.local and add the following lines before the "exit 0" line:**

```
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.sav
```

**4. Enable routing**
Configure the gateway for routing between two interfaces by enabling IP forwarding:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"
```

**5. Edit /etc/sysctl.conf and uncomment:**

```
#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

... so that it reads:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Regards
Sajjad

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was missing IP Forwarding that was the issue, though I followed a different guide to accomplish this, but will try your suggestion soon, as I am reconfiguring the whole setup. If I succeed, I will mark you answer as correct.