# Ubuntu MAAS / Openstack - Nodes No Internet

Tags: networking, server, maas, openstack

I would like to setup an Ubuntu Openstack "super computer" as a class project for my Science and Technology course. However, I am having trouble getting internet to my Nodes. I have tried a myriad of different iptables configurations I found on forums but to no avail. My nodes PXE boot and register with MAAS and I can even power them up through the MAAS GUI. However, the Nodes take about 3 hours to boot up because they can't download from the internet. A brief word on setup:

```
Public IP - eth0: 192.168.64.5 / 192.168.64.0/24
Private IP - eth1: 10.1.1.1 / 10.1.1.0/24
```

Interestingly I can ping the 10.1.1.1 NIC, or even a Node NIC, from the 192.168.64.x network:

```
Janzs-iMac:~ jjanz$ ping -c 4 10.1.1.1
PING 10.1.1.1 (10.1.1.1): 56 data bytes
36 bytes from blair-majex.a55blaster (192.168.64.1): Redirect Host(New addr: 192.168.64.5)
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
4  5  00 0054 150d   0 0000  40  01 59e0 192.168.64.18  10.1.1.1 

64 bytes from 10.1.1.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.516 ms
36 bytes from blair-majex.a55blaster (192.168.64.1): Redirect Host(New addr: 192.168.64.5)
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
4  5  00 0054 1771   0 0000  40  01 577c 192.168.64.18  10.1.1.1 

64 bytes from 10.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.531 ms
36 bytes from blair-majex.a55blaster (192.168.64.1): Redirect Host(New addr: 192.168.64.5)
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
4  5  00 0054 6a5a   0 0000  40  01 0493 192.168.64.18  10.1.1.1 

64 bytes from 10.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.449 ms
36 bytes from blair-majex.a55blaster (192.168.64.1): Redirect Host(New addr: 192.168.64.5)
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
4  5  00 0054 dcfb   0 0000  40  01 91f1 192.168.64.18  10.1.1.1 

64 bytes from 10.1.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.465 ms

--- 10.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.449/0.490/0.531/0.034 ms
```

However when I do the following command from on the MAAS controller:

```
ping -I eth1 192.168.64.5
```

or

```
ping -I eth1 192.168.64.1
```

I get:

```
python@blare-majex:~$ ping -c 4 -I eth1 192.168.64.5
PING 192.168.64.5 (192.168.64.5) from 10.1.1.1 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.1.1.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.1.1.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.1.1.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.1.1.1 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
```

I have posted my complete MAAS setup on the following our website with screen shots: http://sd52.bc.ca/pcs/?p=1633

Thanks for any assistance you can give in helping me figure out what is going on. My students would love to do this project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have same problem as mentioned in this post which I answered there.

[Openstack-Install - Problem with juju bootstrap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717803/openstack-install-problem-with-juju-bootstrap/718820#718820)

You must enable NAT on your region controller in your chosen network model.
check this out and try instructions.